# Link between deities' domains and alignment

Tags: dnd-3.5e, alignment, religions-and-deities, statistics

Major characteristics of deity in D&D 3.5e are domains and alignment. It is common sense that deity with law domain should have lawful alignment, deity with evil domain should have evil alignment etc. , however, I would like to know what is the most common alignment for deities with other domains (e.g. strength, trade etc.).

**Is there any document that provides statistics of domain-alignment dependences for official D&D 3.5e deities and domains?**

To clarify, I imagine that it would look something like this:

\begin{array}{|c|l|}
\hline
\text{Domain} & \text{LG} & \text{LN} & \text{LE} & \text{NG} & \text{N} & \text{NE} & \text{CG} & \text{CN} & \text{CE} \\ \hline
\text{Strength} & 23\% & 12\% & 10\% & 20\% & 2\% & 8\% & 4\% & 2\% & 19\% \\ \hline
\end{array}

So in above example, 23% of deities that have strength domain have LG alignment, 12% have LN alignment and so on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on the list of domains [here](http://ftm3.altervista.org/ASMoNM/domains.html), which I believe to be particularly thorough, I produced a Google document, found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/115mGlOBfpfT6Ea14-ubztAjz8atigFvG-bqEiEMDgt0/edit?usp=sharing). It lists the domains for each deity, then gets their alignments, then counts each alignment, and finally produces a percentage for each. That final table is reproduced below. Entries listed as “—” here are `#DIV/0!` there, that is, they divide by zero since there were no entries.

| Domain | LG | NG | CG | LN | N | CN | LE | NE | CE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Air | 7% | 7% | 20% | 0% | 33% | 20% | 7% | 7% | 0% |
| Animal | 4% | 30% | 11% | 11% | 22% | 15% | 0% | 4% | 4% |
| Army | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Artifice | 0% | 20% | 0% | 0% | 60% | 20% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Avarice | 4% | 4% | 4% | 4% | 35% | 9% | 4% | 22% | 13% |
| Balance | 0% | 0% | 0% | 22% | 78% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Beguilement | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — |
| Bestial | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% |
| Blackwater | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 33% | 0% | 33% | 33% | 0% |
| Blightbringer | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% |
| Cavern | 0% | 9% | 0% | 0% | 45% | 0% | 0% | 18% | 27% |
| Celerity | 0% | 20% | 0% | 0% | 60% | 20% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Celestial | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Chaos | 0% | 1% | 35% | 0% | 4% | 19% | 1% | 1% | 39% |
| Charity | 38% | 50% | 13% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Charm | 0% | 7% | 43% | 0% | 29% | 14% | 7% | 0% | 0% |
| Chastity | 38% | 25% | 25% | 0% | 13% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Chromatic Dragon | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — |
| City | 0% | 50% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 50% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Cold | 14% | 0% | 0% | 14% | 0% | 14% | 14% | 14% | 29% |
| Commerce | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Community | 43% | 43% | 7% | 7% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Competition | 10% | 0% | 10% | 0% | 10% | 10% | 30% | 10% | 20% |
| Corruption | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 14% | 29% | 57% |
| Courage | 44% | 11% | 11% | 0% | 0% | 11% | 0% | 11% | 11% |
| Craft | 10% | 20% | 10% | 0% | 50% | 0% | 10% | 0% | 0% |
| Creation | 20% | 30% | 10% | 0% | 40% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Darkness | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 10% | 50% | 40% |
| Death | 5% | 0% | 0% | 18% | 14% | 0% | 14% | 32% | 18% |
| Deathbound | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% |
| Deathless | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Decay | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% |
| Demonic | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% |
| Destiny | 0% | 0% | 14% | 14% | 43% | 0% | 14% | 14% | 0% |
| Destruction | 0% | 0% | 0% | 5% | 16% | 8% | 8% | 29% | 34% |
| Diabolic | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% |
| Domination | 0% | 0% | 0% | 22% | 0% | 0% | 44% | 11% | 22% |
| Dragon | 9% | 9% | 9% | 9% | 27% | 9% | 9% | 9% | 9% |
| Dragon Below | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% |
| Dream | 0% | 25% | 25% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 25% | 0% | 25% |
| Drow | 0% | 0% | 17% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 83% |
| Dwarf | 29% | 7% | 29% | 0% | 14% | 0% | 14% | 7% | 0% |
| Earth | 5% | 10% | 0% | 5% | 52% | 0% | 5% | 10% | 14% |
| Elf | 0% | 7% | 71% | 0% | 0% | 21% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Emotion | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Endurance | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Entropy | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% |
| Envy | 0% | 22% | 0% | 0% | 11% | 0% | 11% | 33% | 22% |
| Bane | 0% | 0% | 6% | 6% | 6% | 0% | 11% | 22% | 50% |
| Evil | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 3% | 0% | 20% | 35% | 43% |
| Exorcism | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Family | 30% | 50% | 10% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 10% | 0% |
| Fate | 0% | 14% | 0% | 57% | 14% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 14% |
| Feast | 0% | 50% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 50% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Fey | 20% | 40% | 40% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Fire | 0% | 7% | 7% | 0% | 50% | 0% | 7% | 14% | 14% |
| Force | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 67% | 0% | 0% | 33% | 0% |
| Forge | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Fury | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% |
| Gem Dragon | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — |
| Generosity | 25% | 38% | 13% | 13% | 13% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Ghost | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Glory | 57% | 43% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Gluttony | 25% | 25% | 16% | 0% | 9% | 3% | 0% | 9% | 13% |
| Gnome | 13% | 63% | 0% | 0% | 13% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 13% |
| Good | 28% | 36% | 33% | 0% | 3% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Greed | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 25% | 25% | 50% |
| Halfling | 50% | 0% | 0% | 17% | 33% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Hatred | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 57% | 0% | 43% |
| Healing | 24% | 29% | 18% | 0% | 24% | 0% | 0% | 6% | 0% |
| Herald | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Hope | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Humility | 25% | 25% | 0% | 38% | 13% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Hunger | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 33% | 67% |
| Hunt | 0% | 17% | 17% | 0% | 33% | 17% | 0% | 0% | 17% |
| Illusion | 0% | 29% | 14% | 14% | 14% | 14% | 0% | 0% | 14% |
| Inquisition | 78% | 0% | 0% | 22% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Insight | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Joy | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Knowledge | 9% | 11% | 14% | 11% | 41% | 0% | 2% | 9% | 2% |
| Kobold | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% |
| Law | 40% | 0% | 0% | 33% | 3% | 0% | 24% | 0% | 0% |
| Liberation | 0% | 20% | 80% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Life | 0% | 50% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 50% | 0% |
| Luck | 6% | 6% | 17% | 0% | 33% | 17% | 6% | 11% | 6% |
| Lung Dragon | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — |
| Lust | 0% | 19% | 38% | 0% | 6% | 6% | 6% | 6% | 19% |
| Madness | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 6% | 6% | 6% | 44% | 39% |
| Magic | 4% | 8% | 12% | 16% | 28% | 0% | 12% | 8% | 12% |
| Meditation | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Mentalism | 0% | 0% | 0% | 33% | 33% | 0% | 33% | 0% | 0% |
| Metal | 0% | 14% | 0% | 0% | 71% | 0% | 14% | 0% | 0% |
| Metallic Dragon | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — |
| Mind | 11% | 5% | 11% | 5% | 32% | 5% | 11% | 11% | 11% |
| Moon | 0% | 29% | 43% | 0% | 14% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 14% |
| Mysticism | 6% | 6% | 17% | 0% | 6% | 0% | 11% | 17% | 39% |
| Necromancer | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% |
| Night | 0% | 17% | 17% | 0% | 17% | 0% | 0% | 33% | 17% |
| Nobility | 47% | 20% | 13% | 20% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Ocean | 25% | 0% | 25% | 13% | 13% | 0% | 0% | 13% | 13% |
| Ooze | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% |
| Oracle | 8% | 0% | 23% | 8% | 46% | 0% | 0% | 8% | 8% |
| Orc | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 50% | 50% |
| Pact | 33% | 0% | 0% | 17% | 33% | 0% | 0% | 17% | 0% |
| Pain | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 50% | 0% | 50% |
| Passion | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% |
| Patience | 20% | 20% | 10% | 10% | 40% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Pestilence | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 38% | 63% |
| Planning | 0% | 0% | 0% | 50% | 38% | 0% | 0% | 13% | 0% |
| Plant | 4% | 43% | 14% | 4% | 29% | 4% | 0% | 0% | 4% |
| Pleasure | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Portal | 0% | 0% | 50% | 0% | 0% | 50% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Pride | 23% | 5% | 5% | 11% | 11% | 7% | 11% | 11% | 16% |
| Protection | 18% | 18% | 18% | 16% | 24% | 4% | 2% | 0% | 0% |
| Purification | 50% | 25% | 0% | 13% | 0% | 0% | 13% | 0% | 0% |
| Radiance | 20% | 40% | 20% | 20% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Renewal | 0% | 40% | 10% | 0% | 30% | 10% | 0% | 0% | 10% |
| Repose | 20% | 10% | 10% | 60% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Retribution | 30% | 0% | 0% | 30% | 0% | 20% | 10% | 0% | 10% |
| Revered Ancestor | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Rune | 8% | 23% | 31% | 15% | 15% | 0% | 0% | 8% | 0% |
| Sand | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Scalykind | 0% | 0% | 0% | 14% | 29% | 14% | 29% | 14% | 0% |
| Seafolk | 67% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 33% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Seduction | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — |
| Shadow | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 33% | 0% | 0% | 33% | 33% |
| Sky | 0% | 0% | 67% | 0% | 17% | 0% | 0% | 17% | 0% |
| Slime | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 50% | 0% | 50% |
| Sloth | 6% | 17% | 22% | 0% | 22% | 17% | 6% | 11% | 0% |
| Spell | 0% | 17% | 0% | 33% | 50% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Spider | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% |
| Spirit | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — |
| Spite | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% |
| Storm | 11% | 11% | 22% | 0% | 11% | 11% | 0% | 11% | 22% |
| Strength | 8% | 13% | 8% | 13% | 8% | 13% | 16% | 3% | 18% |
| Suffering | 17% | 0% | 0% | 17% | 17% | 0% | 17% | 17% | 17% |
| Summer | 0% | 40% | 0% | 0% | 20% | 20% | 20% | 0% | 0% |
| Summoner | 0% | 14% | 14% | 0% | 43% | 0% | 14% | 0% | 14% |
| Sun | 19% | 63% | 0% | 6% | 13% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Temperance | 55% | 18% | 0% | 18% | 9% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Temptation | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% |
| Thirst | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% |
| Time | 0% | 0% | 25% | 25% | 50% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Trade | 0% | 0% | 14% | 0% | 43% | 29% | 0% | 14% | 0% |
| Transformation | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — |
| Travel | 0% | 15% | 18% | 12% | 35% | 15% | 3% | 0% | 3% |
| Treachery | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% |
| Trickery | 0% | 6% | 6% | 0% | 26% | 12% | 9% | 18% | 24% |
| Truth | 50% | 0% | 0% | 50% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Tyranny | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 50% | 17% | 33% |
| Undead | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — | — |
| Undeath | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 60% | 40% |
| Vile Darkness | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% |
| War | 19% | 2% | 14% | 5% | 10% | 12% | 14% | 10% | 14% |
| Warforged | 0% | 33% | 0% | 0% | 33% | 0% | 33% | 0% | 0% |
| Water | 0% | 10% | 5% | 5% | 45% | 5% | 0% | 25% | 5% |
| Wealth | 0% | 25% | 0% | 0% | 50% | 25% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Weather | 0% | 15% | 23% | 8% | 38% | 8% | 0% | 8% | 0% |
| Windstorm | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| Winter | 25% | 25% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 25% | 0% | 25% | 0% |
| Wrath | 13% | 3% | 10% | 5% | 8% | 10% | 13% | 13% | 25% |
| Zeal | 29% | 7% | 50% | 7% | 0% | 0% | 7% | 0% | 0% |

To look up the alignment for each deity, I used a number of sources (mostly [Curmudgeon’s](http://ftm3.altervista.org/ASMoNM/FavoredWeapons.html) and [IMarvinTPA’s](http://www.imarvintpa.com/dndLive/Index_Deities.php), with the rest found via Google). I still have no data on a Forgotten Realms deity named “Tempest” if anyone knows of that one (searches only found info on the Tempest Domain).

Comment: Do you think there's an option to add "total number of deities"? There are a few with 100% for one alignment, which makes me assume that there's only 1 deity with that domain, but I might be wrong. Would be nice to be able to see maybe.

Comment: @Erik The linked spreadsheet has that information in the Alignment Counts sheet. It wouldn’t fit within the limited width of SE answers, so I can’t add it to the table here.